# How to get the last five characters of a string using Substring() in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I can get the first three characters with the function below.

However, how can I get the output of the last five characters ("Three") with the `Substring()` function? Or will another string function have to be used?

```
static void Main()
{
    string input = "OneTwoThree";

    // Get first three characters
    string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
    Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub); // Output One. 
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If your input string could be less than five characters long then you should be aware that [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the `startIndex` argument is negative.

To solve this potential problem you can use the following code:

```
string sub = input.Substring(Math.Max(0, input.Length - 5));
```

Or more explicitly:

```
public static string Right(string input, int length)
{
    if (length >= input.Length)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return input.Substring(input.Length - length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well. But I found it is a little hard to understand. From MSDN. I found **String::Substring Method** included `String.Substring (Int32) ` and `Substring(Int32, Int32)` . Why not include the style like `Substring(fun())`. I think You insert a fun() as a argument for Substring(). Thank you.

Comment: @Nano HE: `Math.Max(int, int)` returns the highest of the two numbers passed in. So in this case if `input.Length` is less than 5 characters long `Substring` is passed `0` which effectively gives you the whole of `input`. Otherwise you get a substring of the right 5 characters.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  I was running into a very similar issue, and I like how you use the Math functions to get the max length (though I'm using to get the minimum length since the string could be shorter than the length that I was specifying).  I kept running into exceptions due to that issue, but your solution is an elegant way to solve that.

Comment: That was fine. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 14):

```
string sub = input.Substring(input.Length - 5);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you can use extension methods, this will do it in a safe way regardless of string length:

```
public static string Right(this string text, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || maxLength <= 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (maxLength < text.Length)
    {
        return text.Substring(text.Length - maxLength);
    }

    return text;
}
```

And to use it:

```
string sub = input.Right(5);
```

Comment: I really hate that this is not how SubString is implemented out of the box.  It is very common to call Substring(0,LEN) on a string that is less than LEN, and I always prefer that it just work in that case, not throw a darned exception.  I use the Math.Min workaround, but am not happy with it.

Answer (score 10):

```
static void Main()
    {
        string input = "OneTwoThree";

            //Get last 5 characters
        string sub = input.Substring(6);
        Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub); // Output Three. 
    }
```

- `Substring(0, 3)` - Returns substring of first 3 chars. `//One`
- `Substring(3, 3)` - Returns substring of second 3 chars. `//Two`
- `Substring(6)` - Returns substring of all chars after first 6. `//Three`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the `Length` property of the string as part of the input to `Substring`:

```
string sub = input.Substring(input.Length - 5); // Retrieves the last 5 characters of input
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick extension method you can use that mimics PHP syntax. Include `AssemblyName.Extensions` to the code file you are using the extension in.

Then you could call:

```
input.SubstringReverse(-5) and it will return "Three".

namespace AssemblyName.Extensions {

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a negative integer - counts back from the end of the string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        public static string SubstringReverse(this string str, int length)
        {
            if (length > 0) 
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length must be less than zero.");
            }

            if (str.Length < Math.Abs(length))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length cannot be greater than the length of the string.");
            }

            return str.Substring((str.Length + length), Math.Abs(length));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Substring. This method extracts strings. It requires the location of the substring (a start index, a length). It then returns a new string with the characters in that range.

See a small example :

```
string input = "OneTwoThree";
// Get first three characters.
string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
```

Output : 
Substring: One

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

```
string str = null;
string retString = null;
str = "This is substring test";
retString = str.Substring(8, 9);
```

This return "substring"

[C# substring sample source](http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-substring.htm)

Answer (score 0):

simple way to do this in one line of code would be this

```
string sub = input.Substring(input.Length > 5 ? input.Length - 5 : 0);
```

and here some informations about [Operator ? :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "OneTwoThree";
(if input.length >5)
{
string str=input.substring(input.length-5,5);
}
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.

Comment: yaa... sure.. i ll take care of it @ZygD.

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` 8.0 and later you can use `[^5..]` to get the last five characters combined with a `?` operator to avoid a potential `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

```
string input1 = "0123456789";
string input2 = "0123";
Console.WriteLine(input1.Length >= 5 ? input1[^5..] : input1); //returns 56789
Console.WriteLine(input2.Length >= 5 ? input2[^5..] : input2); //returns 0123
```

[index-from-end-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator) and [range-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator)

Answer (score -2):

```
// Get first three characters
string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub); // Output One. 

string sub = input.Substring(6, 5);
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub); //You'll get output: Three
```