# Finding the substring

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that could look like this: smithj_Website1  or it could look like this rodgersk_Website5 etc, etc.  I want to be able to store in a string what is after the "_".  So IE (Website1, Website5,..)

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to get the substring in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2902394/299327)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be a simple as using [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)

```
string mystr = "test_Website1"
string theend = mystr.SubString(mystr.IndexOf("_") + 1)
// theend = "Website1"
```

`mystr.IndexOf("_")` will get the position of the `_` and adding one to it will get the index of the first character after it.  Then don't pass in a second parameter and it will automatically take the substring starting at the character after the `_` and stopping and the end of the string.

Comment: Awesome Bob.. And what if I wanted to get what was in front the "_" in a different string?

Comment: That's a good problem for you to figure out.

Comment: wow thanks palswim.  how nice of you

Comment: I got the last part figured out using remove().  Thanks again Bob and others

Answer (score 3):

```
int startingIndex = inputstring.IndexOf("_") + 1;
string webSite = inputstring.Substring(startingIndex);
```

or, in one line:

```
string webSite = inputstring.Substring(inputstring.IndexOf("_") + 1);
```